How to Implement OpenAPI v3 in Spring 6 (without Spring Boot)?
I am working on a project that uses Spring 6 but does not use Spring Boot. I want to implement OpenAPI v3 to document and interact with my REST API, but I only see examples and documentation on Spring's website that refer to Spring Boot v3.
Is there any way to implement OpenAPI v3 in a Spring 6 application without using Spring Boot? If so, could you provide some guidance or examples on how to do it?
i've alreadt try this solution but it's not working
How to Integrate Open API 3 with Spring project (not Spring Boot) using springdoc-openapi
